# Angular 8 ng test Web Worker fails with "Module scripts are not supported on DedicatedWorker yet"

Tags: angular, unit-testing

Create a new project with Angular CLI and generate a web-worker and test.

```
ng new demo
ng generate web-worker app
ng test --browsers=ChromeHeadless
```

Get Error:

```
TypeError: Failed to construct 'Worker': Module scripts are not supported on DedicatedWorker yet. You can try the feature with '--enable-experimental-web-platform-features' flag (see https://crbug.com/680046)
```

Adding "--enable-experimental-web-platform-features" to the command line fails with "Unknown option". Is it possible to pass "enable-experimental-web-platform-features" as a flag or configure it conditionally?

Comment: did you find solution for this issue?

Comment: @DenisAnisimov not yet unfortunately

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found solution. In angular.json in 'test' section after scripts: [] need to add webWorkerTsConfig field like in build section:

```
"webWorkerTsConfig": "tsconfig.worker.json"
```

My 'test' section now looks like (this is empty project):

```
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "webWorkerTsConfig": "tsconfig.worker.json"
          }
        },
```

hope, help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that might help is mocking the Worker. In my unit tests I added the following:

```
class Windows {
  private url: string;
  private onmessage: (msg: any) => void;
  constructor(stringUrl: string) {
      this.url = stringUrl;
      this.onmessage = () => {};
  }
  postMessage(msg: any) {
      this.onmessage(msg);
  }
}

// @ts-ignore
window.Worker = Worker;
```